# CodeIgniter, set_flashdata not working after redirect

Tags: codeigniter, flash, session

set_flashdata is not working directly after redirect with only one redirect.

I am using one controller in this process - Profilers' Controller. It handles the member confirmation process and also displays the login page on the redirect. The process is as follows:

1. this session set_flashdata ('topic', 'newmember')
2. redirect ('login')
3. route ['login'] = 'profilers/signIn'
4. topic = $this session flashdata ('topic')

I have turned off all database session configuration for cleaner debugging and even though session library is turned on in configs, I have started calling it anyways which doesn't seem to work either.

Here is my code. As you can see, I am sending path info to a log file path.log:

in controller Profilers, function confirmMember:

```
public function confirmMember()
  {
    //use_ssl();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('handle', 'Unique Member Name', 'trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmation', 'Confirmation Code', 'trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[20]|max_length[20]|alpha_numeric');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {echo "here";exit;
      $data['handle']=$this->input->post('handle');
      $data['confirmation']=$this->input->post('confirmation');
      $this->load->view('signing/defaults/header',$data);
      $this->load->view('defaults/heading',$data);
      $this->load->view('defaults/banner');
      $this->load->view('defaults/banner_right');
      $this->load->view('member/temp/index',$data);
      $this->load->view('defaults/footer',$data);
    } else {

      $post = $this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);
      $data['member'] = $this->Signing_model->model_confirmMember($post);

  if ($data['member']['confirmed']!==FALSE) {
    /* PATH CHECK */ 
    error_log("member confirmation not false\n",3, LOG_DIR.'path.log');
    unset($post);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('topic', 'newmember');
    // $this->session->keep_flashdata('topic');
    redirect('login','refresh');
  } else {
    /* PATH CHECK */ 
    error_log("member confirmation IS FALSE\n",3, LOG_DIR.'path.log');
    $this->load->view('member/temp/index',$data);
  }
```

My log file shows that the path is using the correct path and showing "member confirmation not false".

I have tried with keep_flash data on (which I assumed wouldn't work since there are no other redirects) and off.

I have also tried redirect without 'refresh'.

In config/routes.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['join'] = 'profilers/joinUp';
$route['login'] = 'profilers/signIn';
...
```

Login page uses Profilers Controller, signIn function as show above:

```
public function signIn()
{
  $topic = $this->session->flashdata('topic');
  if (isset($topic)) {
      $message = "topic is set. topic = ".$topic."\n";
      if ($topic!==FALSE) {
              error_log("flash var topic is not false\n", 3, LOG_DIR.'path.log');
      } else {
              error_log("flash var topic is FALSE\n", 3, LOG_DIR.'path.log');
      }
  } else {
      $message = "topic is NOT set\n";
  }
  error_log($message,3,LOG_DIR.'path.log');

  exit;
  ...
  ...
}
```

log file is showing that topic is set but is false.

"flash var topic is FALSE"

"topic is set. topic = "

Of course topic var not set since it is FALSE.

As you can see, I have moved the get flash data function to the beginning of my controller function to bypass anything that may be corrupting data.

Comment: Do you get any data if you try to debug it using `echo $this->session->flashdata('topic');die();` immediately after you set it (and before the redirect) in `confirmMember(){}` Also, is it only flash data that isn't working? If you try using a session variable instead does it work?

Comment: No. nothing. Thanks for the speedy reply.

Comment: At the very top of your controller, immediately after the <?php tag, try adding `session_start();` , if you don't have one already.

Comment: Btw, `isset($topic)` will always be true, even if it is null. This is because you create the variable on the line before, thus it exists. You would be better checking for simply  `if($topic){`

Comment: Thanks for the help Jeemusu. That did change things and must have been the issue. It is now showing some errors that I have to grog through. I'll post back in a bit once I get through these errors.

Comment: Okay, after fixing the errors, it still is showing nothing on echo $this->session->flashdata('topic');die();

Comment: what were the errors? FYI, You will need to have `session_start()` at the top of all your controllers that use sessions. And you are definately loading the session library using `$this->load->library('session');` or in your autoloader.php ?

Comment: The errors were related to something else. Sorry for the distraction. I typed in the confirmation credential incorrectly and was showing an incomplete view for false confirmation. library session is loading correctly, and I have re-removed it since I know it is auto-loaded. I am using sessions and flashdata session else where without any problems.

Comment: is the `$data['member']['confirmed']!==FALSE` if statement even being evaluated? Can you add in a line at the top of it with `echo 'foo';die();`. If that doesn't get output, then you'll no it's not even entering the if statement.

Comment: Okay, I've added the rest of the controller. It gets confirmed. This does work. The member gets added to the database and it is confirmed by the path taken - notice it gets written to log via error_log and shows me that it gets confirmed and which path the controller takes. I have commented out use_ssl(), which is a function I found on this site. I commented it out to see if it is causing any issues.

Comment: Alright, in that case, lets try one more thing. After you destroy the session `$this->session->sess_destroy();`, try re-creating it using codeigniters library `$this->session->sess_create(); `. To be honest, you shouldn't need to destroy the session, you should just unset the variables that you want to get rid of.

Comment: use_ssl() doesn't seem to be causing any interference. Removing ssl does not change anything.

Comment: sess_create() not working either. I even tried removing sess_destroy() and still not working.

Comment: I added $this->session->set_userdata('hi', 'hello');echo $this->session->userdata('hi');die(); and I get hello. So normal session seem to work ok.

Comment: Normal sessions work, but flash data doesn't, even if tested immediately after being set... I'm running out of ideas unfortunately, hopefully someone else can help out. My next step would be to try removing all the code and see if you can get just flash data working, then add stuff back in bit by bit and see if you can find whats breaking it. Update us on how it goes.

Comment: Okay. Yes this is mind-boggling. I will start removing code now and doing as you described. Thanks!

Comment: Well not sure what happened, but It looks like it is working now. I'm going to go back and see what was the cause, probably the sess_destroy issue like you said, but I'm also thinking that you can't view flashdata on same controller before redirect as I'm noticing others saying in other forums including this forum.

Comment: sess_destroy() was in fact the culprit. Removing it or adding sess_creat() works after all. It just had to be redirected before I could view the flashdata. Problem solved. Jeemusu, You should officially make this an answer so I can check it. lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to start the session again after you have destroyed it.

Try adding this after your call to `sess_destory()`:

`$this->session->sess_create()`

Alternatively you could avoid destroying the session, and `unset()` the values you wish to get rid of.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jeemusu. Also I should note that we find that calling flashdata within the same file before redirecting may not work.